# Chrome Extension Overlay Page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I create a Chrome Extension and would like to know:

How can I create an overlay over an existing webpage in a chrome extension?

I don't want to use a popup, I would rather prefer a banner at the top or bottom of the page.

I did read the Google Chrome Extension documentation but couldn't find the solution for my problem in it. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: There's no such API, so you'll have to add a standard DOM element to the page and adjust the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a content script that injects an  on the top/bottom of the web page. That is on all **http**, and **https** websites.
Note: This code does not work on the local **chrome://** and **Chrome Web Store** pages.

For example in your **content.js**:

```
var newiframe = document.createElement("iframe");
newiframe.setAttribute("src", chrome.runtime.getURL("html/panel.html"));
newiframe.style.width = "100%";
newiframe.style.top = "0";
newiframe.style.left = "0";
newiframe.style.right= "0";
newiframe.style.position = "absolute";
newiframe.style.zIndex = "500";
newiframe.style.height = "80px";
document.body.appendChild(newiframe);
```

And in your **manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "__MSG_name__",
  "short_name": "Proper Menubar",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "__MSG_description__",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": [ "html/panel.html",
    "js/script.js",
    "css/body.css"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "use_dynamic_url": true
  }],
  "permissions": [ "activeTab" ]
}
```

**panel.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>body{background:red;color:white}</style>
</head>
<body>Hello there</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailled answer. That helped me a lot! I was actually quite close...But sometimes close is just not enough ;)
It works fine for me!

Comment: Great to hear it.